# Attempting to connect to a web socket throws an exception using Rug.OSC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, websocket, osc

.NET Core 3.1
Error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

Code:

```
 IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                int port = 9000;
                OscSender sender = new OscSender(address, port);
                sender.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine("Setting up notification listeners...");
```

This is a console application, is there some permission I need to be adding?